# I want to have a 9v battery to give a 4.5v - 5v power supply?

Tags: pic, breadboard, 5v

I am trying to download a program on to my PIC circuit. As you know the pic isn't supposed to operate with anything larger than 5v. I don't have any access to a battery pack which could hold 3 x AA batteries. What i do have are lods of other stuff, that may be useful. I was thinking that if i used two 330 ohm resistors to create a potential divider then had another battery snap going off from that to the pic circuit. Would that work?

[image: Schematic of theory[![Bread board of theory]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uJNt.jpg)

Comment: Tape or rubberband 3 AA batteries (and some wires or bits of metal) together. Properly bent wires on a protoboard will do, too. Or wedge them into a suitable cardboard, wood or plastic box, or tube (tube may be easier as you don't ned to provide any inter-battery connections.) 9V has MUCH less capacity (amp-hours) than AA - so even if you use a switcher, you'll have comparatively poor runtime. Cost is usually worse, too.

Comment: Why is this being voted negatively

Comment: Google "9V to 5V regulator cap". Or build your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not usually a good idea for a couple of reasons.

- It wastes power. From \$ V = I \cdot R \$ we can calculate the current, \$ I = \frac {V}{R} = \frac {9~V}{660~Ω} = 13.6~mA \$ without doing anything useful!
- More importantly, the voltage will vary depending on what the processor load is. If the PIC has a wide voltage tolerance you might get away with it.

You really need a voltage regulator.

A quick work-around is to use a USB port as power supply. Get a cheap USB cable or broken USB device, keep the A-plug end (that goes into your computer) and cut the plug or device off the other end. The red (+) and black (-) should give you a 5 V regulated and current-limited supply. Check with your multimeter.

**USB cable pintout**

```
Red   | Vcc (+5 V)     | Connect to circuit +
White | USB Data -     | Not used
Green | USB Data +     | Not used
Black | Ground         | Connect to circuit -
Shield|                | Not used (probably connects to laptop ground)
```

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks. So the potential divider won't work?

Comment: Very good answer ! I did not consider a USB supply

Comment: What do i do with the earth wires?

Comment: I presume you mean the shield / screen. See update. If you have a USB charger you may wish to use it in preference to your laptop. Cost of replacement will be less if you have an accident. If you're only running a few LEDs or similar from your PIC it is very unlikely that you could cause any damage.

Comment: @HasanImtiaz: The potential divider _might_ work but consider what would happen if the PIC went from drawing almost zero current to drawing 20 mA. The voltage would collapse from 4.5 V to, maybe, 2 V. You need to regulate the supply.

Comment: @transistor I cut an old USB cable stripped it, and soldered it to the battery snap and now the PIc is downloading programs fine. Thank you

Comment: Can you add a photo of the arrangement? Since you don't need a battery, why are you using the battery snap? The USB + and - should go straight to your PIC circuit.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a voltage divider along with a voltage-buffer OpAmp. (if you connect the pic directly the voltage diviser output, it will not work since it will draw current)

Comment: I don't have access to many things, which is why i am asking otherwise i would order a 3x AA battery pack, but delivery is 10 pounds and I don't want to spend that kind of money for a 50p thing. Will the potential divider work? I'm asking because i have only just started my ecpirience with electronics?

Comment: voltage divider alone will not work, because its output current has to be zero, that's why I was suggesting a voltage buffer. Can't you just buy those 3 AA batteries in a shop or something ?

Comment: Then how would i connect it to the circuit?

Comment: What about wires ?

Comment: I understand how it would work with a 9v battery. How'd i do that with aa batteries

Comment: Use a battery holder. http://cpc.farnell.com/1/1/9959-pro-power-23vb31b-battery-holder-3xaa-snap.html

Answer (score 0):

Simple : Use voltage regulator L7805.(as @transistor already answered)

[image: vr]

Output voltage : 5.2V approx(always more than 5V if input voltage 9V or more)

Answer (score 0):

If cost permits, you may want to have Linear Technologies LTM4623 micro switching power supply module. This finger nail size chip can buck down 9v to 5v at 85% efficiency, just needed a voltage setting fixed resistor and two equally tiny capacitors at input and output. Great performance for battery powered loads. The only concern it costs usd10 a piece. Check their website.